# Changed AngularJS value from method does not persist after refresh

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to modify the value of a module value in AngularJS but it does not persist. If I click around the app after its modified its fine but the moment I refresh the page it get returned to the default value. How can I change the value and have it persist while the app is being used.

Here is the value:

```
;(function() {
  angular.module('app.common')
    .value('config', {
      date: {
        dateFormat: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
        angularDateFormat: 'yyyy-MM-d',
        d3DateFormat: '%Y-%m-%d %I:%M %p'
      },
      multiLineSelectMode: 'single',
      labels: {
        success: { single: 'Success', plural: 'Successes' },
        warning: { single: 'Warning', plural: 'Warnings' },
        danger: { single: 'Danger', plural: 'Dangers' },
        dashboard: { title: 'Dashboard', single: 'Dashboard', plural: 'Dashboards' },
        operations: { title: 'Operations', single: 'Operation', plural: 'Operations' },
        locations: { title: 'Locations', single: 'Location', plural: 'Locations' },
        devices: { title: 'Devices', single: 'Device', plural: 'Devices' },
        customers: { title: 'Customers', single: 'Customer', plural: 'Customers' },
        transactions: { title: 'Transactions', single: 'Transaction', plural: 'Transaction' },
        payments: { title: 'Payments', single: 'Payment', plural: 'Payments' },
        inventory: { title: 'Inventory', single: 'Inventory', plural: 'Inventories' },
        iotCampaigns: { title: 'IoT Campaigns', single: 'IoT Campaign', plural: 'IoT Campaigns' },
        marketing: { title: 'Marketing', single: 'Campaign', plural: 'Campaigns' },
        incidents: { title: 'Incidents', single: 'Incident', plural: 'Incidents' },
        reporting: { title: 'Reporting', single: 'Report', plural: 'Reports' }
      }
    }
  );
})();
```

and here is where I am trying to modify it from another module/file

```
;(function() {
  angular
    .module('app.configuration')
    .controller('LabelConfigCtrl', LabelConfigCtrl);

  LabelConfigCtrl.$inject = ['config', 'ConfigurationService'];

  function LabelConfigCtrl(config, ConfigurationService) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.labelModel = config.labels;

    vm.updateConfig = function() {
      config = vm.labelModel; <-- this does not persist if I refresh the page
    }
  }
})();
```

`vm.labelModel` is attached to a big form that modifies the value through `ng-model`

Comment: Would you clarify the part about refreshing the page? Do you mean a page reload? Unless you are storing to `localStorage` or saving to a database, nothing will persist in an AngularJS application when you refresh the page.

Comment: Read [MDN Web API Reference - localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API)

Comment: Ah localStorage will have to do. For some reason I thought that that value would persist over page reload. Don't know why I thought that thanks!